# counting record types in a mongo aggregation (pymongo)

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am doing the following aggregation using pymongo (`users` is defined previously as the list of users I want to query for):

```
    pipeline = [
        { '$match': {'user': {'$in': users} },
        { '$group': { '_id': "$user", 'badges': {'$push': '$badge'} } },
    ]
```

This gives me the following results:

```
{u'ok': 1.0,
 u'result': [{u'_id': u'user22',
              u'badges': [u'gold', u'silver', u'silver']},
             {u'_id': u'user2',
              u'badges': [u'gold', u'gold']},
             {u'_id': u'user15',
              u'badges': [u'gold', u'bronze', u'bronze']},
             {u'_id': u'user11',
              u'badges': [u'gold']},
             {u'_id': u'user3',
              u'badges': [u'silver', u'bronze']},
             {u'_id': u'user18',
              u'badges': [u'bronze']}
            ]
}
```

This is ok, but what I really want to get is a count per medal type (type=gold/silver/bronze).  I can do this easily in post-processing in Python, but I feel like I should be able to do it in the same pipeline and I want to learn "how to mongo better" :)

So to be clear, what I really want is this (I generated this ideal output by hand so there might be an inconsistency w/ the data above or a syntax error, but I think it gets the point across):

```
{u'ok': 1.0,
 u'result': [{u'_id': u'user22',
              u'badges': {u'gold': 1, u'silver': 2}},
             {u'_id': u'user2',
              u'badges': {u'gold': 2}},
             {u'_id': u'user15',
              u'badges': {u'gold': 1, u'bronze': 2}},
             {u'_id': u'user11',
              u'badges': {u'gold': 1}},
             {u'_id': u'user3',
              u'badges': {u'silver': 1, u'bronze': 1}},
             {u'_id': u'user18',
              u'badges': {u'bronze': 1}}
            ]
}
```

My data-structure requirements aren't rigid.  I would also be happy with using gold/silver/bronze as the keys and avoiding having the nested dict:

```
{u'_id': u'user22',
 u'gold': 1, u'silver': 2},
{u'_id': u'user2',
 u'gold': 2},
...
```

I tried doing a bunch of things with the `$sum` operator, but with no luck.  When I try to dynamically generate a field name I get:

`failed: exception: the group aggregate field name '$badge' cannot be an operator name`

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance!

(Also, semi-related...I don't know much about map-reduce.  Maybe this is a candidate for that.  I started using aggregations and they have worked so far for me, til now.  I should probably learn about map-reduce too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could rather do other than pushing the badges to an array is conditionally [**`$sum`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) on the badge type. This is generally done by testing an [**`$eq`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/) condition inside a [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator in order to determine the amount to contribute to the "sum total":

```js
collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "user": { "$in": users } } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$user",
        "gold": { 
            "$sum": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$badge", "gold" ] },
                    1,
                    0
                ]
            }
        },
        "silver": { 
            "$sum": {
                "$cond": [
                     { "$eq": [ "$badge", "silver" ] },
                     1,
                     0
                ]
            }
        },
        "bronze": { 
            "$sum": {
                "$cond": [
                     { "$eq": [ "$badge", "bronze" ] },
                     1,
                     0
                ]
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

That will correctly sum each type through of course there will be a count for "gold/silver/bronze" for each user regardless of whether it is greater than 0 or not. What you cannot do is "dynamically" create fields in the aggregation framework.

If you really need "dynamic" fields then your only option is mapReduce, but of course that will not be as efficient as the aggregation framework. The conditional sum really does give you the best option.

Comment: Thanks for the update @neil-lunn .  Now that I see how you added the `$cond` in it looks like I was missing the braces around the first parameter - I'm still getting used to all the punctuation.